# the Date class i wrote crashes when i call parameterized constructor but runs cool when default constructor runs

Tags: c++, oop

this is default constructor

```
Date::Date():day(1), month(1), year(1990){
}
```

this is parameterized

```
Date::Date(int day, int month, int year){
this->day = dayTest(day);
this->month = monthTest(month);
this->year = yearTest(year);
}
```

when i try to call parameterized constructor like this:

```
Date obj(12, 12, 1900); //dd/mm/yyyy
```

the program crashes, here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;

Date::Date():day(1), month(1), year(1990){
}

Date::Date(int day, int month, int year){
this->day = dayTest(day);
this->month = monthTest(month);
this->year = yearTest(year);
}

void Date::setDay(int day){

this->day = dayTest(day);
}

void Date::setMonth(int month){

this->month = monthTest(month);
}

void Date::setYear(int year){
this->year = yearTest(year);
}

int Date::dayTest(int day){
const int totalDaysInMonths[13] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 
31, 30, 31};
if(day > 0 && day <= totalDaysInMonths[month])
        return day;
if(month == 2 && day == 29 && ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 
400 ==0))
        return day;
else
    return 1;
}

int Date::monthTest(int month){
if(month > 0 && month <= 12){
    return month;
}else{
    return 1;
}
}

int Date::yearTest(int year){
if(year >= 1900 && year <= 2050){
    return year;
}else{
    return 1990;
}
}

void Date::printDate()const{
cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
}
```

Comment: When you run the `dayTest` you haven't set `month` yet, so who knows what happens in `totalDaysInMonths[month]`?

Comment: @BoPersson so should i make the pattern like mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: No, but perhaps you should validate year first, then month, and then day. Some years there is 29 days in February, so you might need to know the year first anyway.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks sir!